# I need to add the numbers in two cells or return specific text if no numbers are entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am adding the values in two cells; I want the final column to reflect the total; however, some cells have n/a entered for the value intentionally.  How do I reflect the number or n/a in the total column?

if I have the following:

A1 = 1

B1 = 3

C1 when using sum(A1,B1) or (A1:B1) return 4

However, if A1 has 3 and B1 has N/A , I want C1 to reflect N/A.

I have used the following formula which works to produce 0 in column C1 but i want it to return N/A if that is the value input by me.

=SUM(SUMIF(A1:BA,{"N/A"},A1:B1))

Comment: Did you mean to type "How do I reflect the number _of_ n/a in the totals column?" Please show us an example of your values, the formulas you created so far, and what happens when you try them. Click [edit] to put them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In C1 put:

```
=IF(OR(A1:B1 = "N/A"),"N/A",SUM(A1:B1))
```

[image]

Comment: I get a #VALUE error

Comment: @KatJenn not sure why, it works for me.  See edit.

Comment: @KatJenn try separating the cells: `=IF(OR(A1 = "N/A",B1 = "N/A"),"N/A",SUM(A1:B1))`

Comment: it works for me when I separate the cells. TY!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try these one also:*

[image]

---

**Situation 1:**

- Formula in cell `E60`:

  ```
  =IF(COUNTIF(C60:D60,C60)=COUNTA(C60:D60),SUM(C60:D60),"#NA")
  ```

**N.B.**

- This works when both cell has same value (*like here are `1`*).

---

**Situation 2:**

- Formula in cell `F65`:

  `=IF(COUNTIF(C65:E65,"#NA")>=1,"#NA",SUM(C65:E65))`

**N.B.**

- This works when cell has mixed value (*like here are `1` & `2`*).

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*